# How to find the sum of all nodes in a tree

Tags: python, tree

This is how the node is defined:
 A Node is an object
 - Value: Number
 - Children: List of Nodes

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key, childnodes):
        self.key = key
        self.childnodes = childnodes

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Node({self.key!r}, {self.childnodes!r})


testTree = Node(1, [Node(2, []), Node(3, [Node(4, [Node(5, []), Node(6, [Node(7, [])])])])])
```

The code I've been trying is:

```
def sum_of_nodes(root):
    if root is None:
        return 0
    return root.key + sum_of_nodes(root.childnodes[0]) + sum_of_nodes(root.childnodes[1])
```

However I get the error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
>   File "D: /Documents/project1.py", line 170, in <module>  
>   print (f'sum_of_nodes (exampleTree) => {sum_of_nodes (exampleTree)}') # 28  
>   File "D: /Documents/project1.py", line 81, in sum_of_nodes  
>   return root.value + sum_of_nodes (root.subnodes[0]) + sum_of_nodes (root.subnodes[1])  
>   File "D: /Documents/project1.py", line 81, in sum_of_nodes  
>   return root.value + sum_of_nodes (root.subnodes[0]) + sum_of_nodes (root.subnodes[1])  
> IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

Comment: What have you done to debug it?

Comment: You're assuming a non-null node always has two children.  What if a node has a key, but no children, or only one child?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using indexing to lookup the child nodes, you can use a `for` loop:

```
def sum_of_nodes(root):
  return root.key+sum(sum_of_nodes(i) for i in root.childnodes)

print(sum_of_nodes(testTree))
```

Output:

```
28
```

Comment: This is nice because you don't need to handle the base case separately; when a node has no children, the sum is over an empty sequence so there are no more recursive calls.

Comment: @kaya3 Right, the `for` loop more cleanly terminates the recursion, as `sum` applied to an empty iterator is just `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive approach to sum the nodes. The recursive call only happens if the node is not None. Add the value of the current node, then check if it has any children. If so, iterate over each child, call the recursive method, and add the resulting `final_sum` to the current node's `final_sum`. Each function call has its own value of `final_sum`, but the function call on the root node will accumulate `final_sum` across all child nodes.

```
def get_sum(node):
    final_sum = 0
    if node is not None:
        final_sum += node.key
        if node.childnodes is not None:
            for child in node.childnodes:
                final_sum += get_sum(child)
    return final_sum
```

Comment: You need to declare `final_sum = 0`. It's also not necessary to check `len(node.childnodes) > 0` before iterating over it; a `for` loop over an empty list does nothing. It's not clear whether `node` or `node.childnodes` can ever actually be `None`.